# How can I have a global theme with different TextView and Spinner text colors?

Tags: android, styles, themes, textview, spinner

I'm writing an App which needs the following two things:

- The general text (in `TextView`s) needs to be one color (white, in this case - dark background)
- The text on a `Spinner` needs to be a different color (black, since white's too hard to read)

I used a theme, applied at the Application level in the manifest, to perform the first item above.

```
<resources>
    <style name="GlobalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Worked great. Except it also makes the text on the spinner white, which is hard to read.

OK, so I want the *spinner* color to still be black but everything *else* be white.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159113/android-where-is-the-spinner-widgets-text-color-attribute-hiding) which showed how to set the Spinner text color, and it works, but only when I'm not also setting the global textColor as well.

So the following does not work:

```
<resources>
    <style name="GlobalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/GlobalThemeSpinnerItem</item>
    </style>
    <style name="GlobalThemeSpinnerItem" parent="android:Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/GlobalThemeTextAppearanceSpinnerItem</item>
    </style>
    <style name="GlobalThemeTextAppearanceSpinnerItem" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I guess I was hoping that this would be like CSS and things would cascade down (i.e., "all text shall be white, *except* that which is in a spinner"). If I remove the `android:textColor` line in the main theme, the spinner color trick works fine.

It looks like the `SpinnerItem` derives from `TextView` so I tried to come up with a `textViewStyle`-type separation similar to the `spinnerItemStyle` separation, but didn't have any luck.

Unlike most people who ask about this, I want to keep it in the XML as much as possible. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why can't you use parent="android:Widget.TextView" for one color and parent="android:Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem" for the other?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="GlobalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/GlobalThemeSpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/GlobalThemeTextViewItem</item>
</style>

<style name="GlobalThemeTextViewItem" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/GlobalThemeTextAppearanceTextViewItem</item>
</style>
<style name="GlobalThemeTextAppearanceTextViewItem" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

<style name="GlobalThemeSpinnerItem" parent="android:Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/GlobalThemeTextAppearanceSpinnerItem</item>
</style>
<style name="GlobalThemeTextAppearanceSpinnerItem" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

This will make the text in your TextViews white and the text in your Spinners black.