# change the size in spinner

Tags: android

How can change the size of each item area . Look at the red line to understand what I mean.
I use class to create the spinner and have this method which I think I can change the size
to make it more large.
But I don't know which attribute I should use

Image :
http://store3.up-00.com/Nov12/e5Z93428.png

```
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView label = new TextView(context);
        label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

}
```

Comment: give custom row layout for your spinner row

Comment: Try increasing the font size of the `Textview`

Comment: Hi try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9613363/603744 . By this you can customize your spinner as you wish

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    Home.Home_Group, R.layout.my_spinner_style,yourstringarray) i do as this but the can not find R.layout.my_spinner_style even i creat it in my layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the Layout Parameters of your TextView and add Up and Bottom Padding to it!!
Make a new Layout with a textview inside it. You can make this TextView meet your desired design. Lets say you give an id to the textview and the id is: @+id/tvDesign. Then you can follow the code below.

An example would be:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(((TextView) findViewById(tvDesign)).getLayoutParams());
```

Comment: what about the the return do i return the lable or the TextView

Comment: In your code you will add the textview to convertView and you will return it!