# Issue with text color on Spinner in Android App

Tags: android

I'm having this issue:

I have a Spinner (ComboBox) in my Android App that it is filled up with a SimpleCursorAdapter that contains data from the database. The Spinner is filled up correctly, the problem is that it displays the items in white, even though i put the property android:textColor = "#000000" in the XML file (layout) that declares the Spinner...

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Spinner` doesn't have an attribute named "**android:textColor**".

You can set it in `Adapter` or use Custom Spinner

**Links to set Spinner text color :**

- [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9613363/1329126)
- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6159199/1329126)
- [Link 3](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/02/20/how-to-create-custom-layout-for-your-spinner-in-android-or-customizable-spinner-2/)