# How to change Spinner's dropdown list color

Tags: android, spinner

Search alot on but doesn't find a correct answer. I've a `AlertDialogbox` that displays `Spinner` with dropdown list. Everythings works fine but when click on spinner the dropdown list `background` color is `dark grey` and `list item color` is `black`. So its quite difficult to see list item. Is there any way to set list item color to white so that it is  visible. Thanks in advance

```
fSpinner = (Spinner)alertView.findViewById(R.id.fSpinner);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String> (MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,providers);
            fSpinner.setAdapter(adp);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9613363/603744 This is not a complete answer. But this shows how to build your own layout for a spinner's dropdown. Try modifying this for your use case.

Comment: Override getDropDownView() of the Adapter and pass your required view..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just add  `android:popupBackground="#000000"`

Comment: i'm just creating a test application.