# How to change spinner item text color programmatically without using adapter when set its state as disabled

Tags: android, spinner

I am using a spinner in my application  and setting its item values via xml. I have set spinner item default color via style, I have to enable and disable my spinner as required in my application.
I want to change its item color programmatically when I set its state disable. I have searched through google but could not find any solution for this.Is there anyone who has any idea about this how can I set it.I have used this link [how do you set the spinner text color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611220/how-do-you-set-the-spinner-text-color), but it is giving null pointer exception.

```
    m_spnDia = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spiDia);
TextView oTextView = (TextView)m_spnDia.getChildAt(0);
oTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom layout for your spinner item as like created here :

[How to change spinner text size and text color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476665/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-and-text-color)

and use it inside your ArrayAdapter.

Now, As per your requirement you have to create two xml files to provide two different colors to spinner items :

1) When your Spinner is Enabled.

2) When your Spinner is Disabled.

Just change the line below as :

```
if(spinner1.isEnabled){
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item1,list);
}else{
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item2,list);
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply  in my case this can be hectic because I am using a table layout in my app and there are more than 5 spinner in a row and  I have set to set it for all those .