# Android Text color for Spinner with custom Style

Tags: android, spinner, customization, textcolor

I'm trying to set the text color for the Spinner style defined below. However I get the error  "Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget'."   What should "parent" be for "holoSpinnerTextStyle"?

```
<!-- SPINNER -->
        <style name="holoSpinner" parent="@android:style/Theme">
          <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_holo_sel</item>
          <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
          <item name="android:paddingTop">15dip</item>
          <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dip</item>
          <item name="android:paddingRight">25dip</item>
          <item name="android:paddingLeft">25dip</item>
           <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/holoSpinnerTextStyle</item>
          <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        </style>

        <style name="holoSpinnerTextStyle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
          <item name="android:textSize">21sp</item>
          <item name="android:textColor">#9e9d9d</item>
          <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>

        </style>
```

Comment: Have you tried just leaving off the parent attribute?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159113/android-where-is-the-spinner-widgets-text-color-attribute-hiding  ...and the answer is there.