# How to change text color in spinner without using textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I want to change text color for spinner **without using `textView`**, I have already searched and found some tutorials [Android: Where is the Spinner widget's text color attribute hiding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159113/android-where-is-the-spinner-widgets-text-color-attribute-hiding)

but the main thing is they have used `textView`.

```
<Spinner 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_width="0dp" 
     android:layout_weight="1" 
     android:entries="@array/Gender_Selection_arrays" 
     android:prompt="@string/Gender_Selection"
     android:id="@+id/gendersel"
     android:popupBackground="#67656c"/>
```

I know this code is not to change text color.

I have no idea how to do that,please guide me for doing the same.

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got solution for this, Create a new xml "spinner_style.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/Black" />
```

And fix this layout as your spinner style in your activity:

```
   ArrayAdapter<String > gender_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_style,gender_spinner );
```

Answer (score 2):

**Your Spinner**

```
<Spinner 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:entries="@array/Gender_Selection_arrays" 
    android:prompt="@string/Gender_Selection"
    android:id="@+id/gendersel"
    style="@style/mySpinnerItemStyle"
    android:popupBackground="#67656c"/>
```

**mySpinnerItemStyle** (Add this to styles.xml)

```
<style name="mySpinnerItemStyle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_spinner_text_color</item>
</style>
```

And finally in colors.xml

```
<color name="my_spinner_text_color">#FFFFFF</color>
```

*mySpinnerItemStyle* inherits from *Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner* and in that *android:textColor* attribute changes the color of the spinner text

Comment: thank you for your answer but your answer is working only for changing popupbackground color, not text color.

Comment: try `android:foreground` instead of `android:textColor`

Comment: Maybe this will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159113/android-where-is-the-spinner-widgets-text-color-attribute-hiding?lq=1